# set matrix elements to 1 via vector

Tags: matlab

I have a vector

```
a = [1;
     3];
```

I have a matrix:

```
B = [0,0,0;
     0,0,0];
```

I want to set the a-th elements of the matrix to ones such that

```
B = [1,0,0;
     0,0,1];
```

How can I do it without a for loop?

Comment: I assume `a` is a row vector and `b` has as many rows as the columns of `a`. The complexity of any optimal solution will be O(N) where `N` is the number of columns in `a`. So you will need a loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sub2ind` matlab function for that. It creates the so called linear indices, which you can use to index matrices instead of row-column indices:

```
% size of the B matrix
sz=[2,3];

% column indices
a = [1,3];

% row indices
b = [1:sz(1)];

% initialize B
B=zeros(sz);

% set values in B
B(sub2ind(sz,b,a))=1

B =

 1     0     0
 0     0     1
```

It is essentially the same as Oleg proposed, just using a matlab built-in function to compute the linear index, instead of doing it by hand. This is approach does not require you to know how the matrices are stored internally.

Comment: What do you mean by, *"does not require you to know how the matrices are stored internally"*?

Comment: @OlegKomarov I guess that this means that you don't need to know that MATLAB stores matrices column-major, and that `sub2ind` does all the calculations for you.

Comment: @EitanT Could be, but then the claim is not justified since you should know the order of the subs you supply to `sub2ind()`.

Comment: @OlegKomarov I didn't quite understand why that isn't justified. Anyway, it's undeniable that `sub2ind` is prettier.

Comment: @OlegKomarov The point is, why did you calculate `pos` as `(a-1)*sz(1) + (1:sz(1));` and not as `(1:sz(1)-1)*sz(2) + a;`. You made an assumption about how the matrix is stored in memory: column by column. That is true with MATLAB, but using `sub2ind` frees you from having to know that. This is what I meant by my statement.

Comment: @EitanT and angainor My mistake, the column-major logic is so rooted in me that I did not get the point at first (and that's why I almost never use sub2ind).

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `a` are column subs, while row subs are `1:numel(a)`:

```
a = [1,3];

% Retrieve output size
sz     = [numel(a) max(a)];
% preallocate
B      = zeros(sz);
% calculate positions
pos    = (a-1)*sz(1) + (1:sz(1));
B(pos) = 1
```

**NOTE**: MATLAB indexes arrays along the first dimension, then the second and so forth where the 1st on is along rows. This logic lies behind the manually calculated positions.